# What does the word "hacking" or "hacker" come from?

Tags: etymology, slang, business-language, programming, computing

Is there a history behind the word "hacker" and "hacking"?

Could it have anything to do with "hashing" i.e. using a hash function?

Comment: [Hacker](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html) From the jargon file. A source for all hacker related questions!

Comment: Related to this question, what are the roots of the word "hack" used in this context: "He is a talentless hack."

Comment: Of note, common 'hacker lore' has it that there's a distinction between hackers and crackers. Crackers break into computer systems, hackers do not necessarily. Hacking is more an engineering thing than the malicious computer security meaning the media portrays (technically a subset), "e.g. he hacked his washing machine"

Comment: @Ariel: that use of *hack* is well-attested as deriving from hackney carriage, implying a tired old cab-horse, and also giving us *hackneyed*. How and why Hackney gave its name to a horse-drawn cab I know not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the [Jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hacker.html),

> [originally, someone who makes furniture with an axe]

That's essentially the gist: you don't produce quality software, you don't develop, you don't project. You take an idea or someone else's piece of software and hack it roughly with a software equivalent of an [axe](http://www.perl.org/), to form something that fits your own idea of "mostly working" — sometimes the idea being quite far from what general populace would find acceptable. Bypass limitations imposed for business or political (or even safety) reasons, bind different completely mismatching systems together for some weird results, and generally do to computers things that can't be named by any professional terminology, but are quite equivalent to hacking some item with an axe to make it function as something entirely different (say, turning an armchair into a swing).

So, this is not a morph of some word or direct use of some obscure meaning of 'to hack', it's a metaphorical use of the very basic meaning — *to cut or chop with repeated and irregular blows.*

Comment: What's the 'Jargon file'? If it is online, can you edit your answer to put in the link? If it is paper, can you give a fuller reference? Also, if you are quoting the source, can you block off eactly which part is quoted?

Comment: The **vast** majority of the Jargon file link disagrees with your answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's not related to *hashing*.

The roots of *hacker* can be found from the Tech Model Railroad Club of MIT. In 1959, TMRC  member Peter R. Samson complied a [dictionary](http://www.gricer.com/tmrc/dictionary1959.html), which contained both the root work, *hack*, and its derivative, *hacker*. The italics are Samson comments from 2006:

> ```
> HACK: 1) something done without constructive end; 2) a project under-
>            taken on bad self-advice; 3) an entropy booster; 4) to produce,
>            or attempt to produce, a hack.
> ```
>
> *I saw this as a term for an unconventional or unorthodox application of technology, typically deprecated for engineering reasons. There was no specific suggestion of malicious intent (or of benevolence, either). Indeed, the era of this dictionary saw some "good hacks:" using a room-sized computer to play music, for instance; or, some would say, writing the dictionary itself.*
>
> ```
> HACKER: one who hacks, or makes them.
> ```
>
> *A hacker avoids the standard solution. The hack is the basic concept; the hacker is defined in terms of it.*

Perhaps the original meaning was similar to hacking through an immense jungle with a machete, it can go on forever.

---

In fact, the OED also defines *hack* as a tool for breaking or chopping up, dating from before 1300:

> He lened him þan a-pon his hak, Wit seth his sun þus-gat he spak.

And *hacker* follows. From 1620:

> One good hacker, being a lusty labourer, will at good ease hack or cut more than half an acre of ground in a day.

So the sense of mangling and bodging together software and/or hardware isn't too far off.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer and for rejecting my hypothesis that it was related to hashing.

Comment: Here's some modern definitions of *[hacker](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/17632/what-is-the-common-definition-of-a-hacker)*, written by programmers.

Answer (score 4):

The OED’s definition 1d of *hacking* is

> The use of a computer for the satisfaction it gives; the activity of a
>   hacker

The earliest citation is dated 1976:

> The compulsive programmer spends all the time he can working on one of
>   his big projects. ‘Working’ is not the word he uses; he calls what he
>   does ‘hacking’.

In the same year, *hacker* is found meaning

> A person who uses his skill with computers to try to gain unauthorized
>   access to computer files or networks.

My own speculation is that the technological meaning may be related to the use of the verb *hack* to mean *To cope with, manage, accomplish.*

Comment: Thanks for the investigation dating the usage to 1976. Another answer here connect the use of the word hacker with a furniture-hacker who hacks to make furniture.

Answer (score 2):

The Chinese love to transliterate words and find a parallel meaning. The English word *hacker* is translated as 黑客 [hēi kè], literally “dark visitor,” an apt translation for the hacker’s covert actions.

While other have given you a correct English etymology, I hope that this back translation will give you some insight into the connotation. It is more at "secretive" and "destructive," and the resemblence to a computer hash function is accidental.