# Name for a device purposefully put together from faulty parts

Tags: terminology, technical

A tech jargon question: A friend thought he once heard a funny (?) jargon word for a device that was put together from faulty parts on purpose, maybe even with the very questionable intention to sell it as an online auction as "broken, but ready to get fixed by someone who knows a little electionics". If you were to buy the device, knowing typical failures and using good troubleshooting skills would not help you much because the device is pretty much a good-looking heap of junk sub-assemblies and has not failed for the reasons things usually fail.

Example: Someone has three bad laser printers of the same brand and model, and lucks out and is able to build two good ones from all the parts and sub-assemblies. Then, everything that's left is taken, being put together into a third, very broken printer and maybe even sold "as is" (very bad, of course), "with need to be fixed" (still bad, because someone intentionally sells junk and not just a device that went bad for just one reason), or "for parts salvaging" (still bad, because someone knowingly offers more bad parts than anybody could reasonably expect from the offer).

Now, ... what's the word for the junk device?

Any chance the word my friend is trying to remember was "diva" or something similar? As in its derogatory/slang meaning - good-looking but often useless - sometimes found with high-nosed personalities, and not limited to the original female context, but also heard when talking about male soccer stars.

Comment: I suppose the Trojan Horse was the original example of this, if you allow that parts intended to kill could be termed faulty even if they function as designed.  ^_^

Comment: Bricolage is the hobby of assembling new things out of junk you have lying around. This seems related, but sinister.

Comment: Hmmm... Trojan Horse seems to fit, almost -- intentionally passing off something defective (or in this case deadly) as something nice.

Comment: A highly related concept is [planned obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planned_obsolescence), where you try to design or manufacture a product defective to force a buyer to replace or upgrade before a quality product would be expected to break. That said, I'm not familiar with any equivalent term for cobbling or scrounging such a product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping to the popular use of automobile terminology, a *lemon* is something (usually a vehicle) the seller knows to be impaired but the buyer believes to be good.

Answer (score 8):

How about a **shiny turd**, or **polished turd** ?
(I've heard both variants, while living in the UK. First one is more common.)

Looks good on the outside, inside is another matter.

Comment: "Polished turd" works well here in the US too -- something that's a steaming pile of crap, but touched up so it looks more attractive than what it actually is. At the end of the day, a polished turd is still a turd. There's also the verb form, "polishing a turd", frequently said of coders who are attempting to patch and fix a program that is hopelessly broken; in this case it's generally meant more to imply that the work being done is pointless, rather than that it's being done with malice.

Comment: @DoktorJ Polishing a turd is actually possible, as the Mythbusters demonstrated a couple of years ago :-)

Comment: no one ever said it wasn't possible -- but even though it's polished, it is still a turd isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

**cut and shut**

I suggest you adopt the terminology that is used for cars. This is the term used in the UK. I'm not certain about US terminology.

> A ‘cut and shut’ car is one of the biggest dangers to a car buyer. A
>   cut and shut consists of two or more cars welded together. Usually,
>   this happens when a car is damaged enough to be written off by
>   insurers and is patched together with another car to hide the damage.
>
> They are incredibly dangerous because the structural integrity of the
>   car has been altered and can be a deathtrap if it is involved in a
>   collision.
>
> http://www.perrys.co.uk/car-news/buyers-guides/guide-checking-a-car-for-signs-of-cut-and-shut/

Comment: This is really close, but maybe not exactly what I'm looking for. "Cut" refers to the cassis being taken apart and welded together. To stick to the example of cars, I was thinking of a chassis stuffed with a bad clutch, bad gears, a broken air condition and maybe a dashboard with a low-mile odometer. Maybe cut and shut is used for such cars as well, but the process didn't involve cutting.

Comment: @zebonaut - I think they call that a 'lemon'.

Comment: I think I get it: A sour deal. Would 'lemon' be equally common in BE and AE, as wikipedia suggests, and used outside the context of cars, too? (Also, here are sources: http://www.powerwriting.com/vw-lemon-ad.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_%28automobile%29)

Comment: I've reached the limit of my knowledge on this subject! Let's see if there are other answers.

Comment: A cut and shut from a chop shop.

Comment: This one misses a key element in the original question: it implies malicious negligence, i.e. the product is sold without explanation of its defects to the customer. The original question describes items made of junk components and advertised as such.

Comment: @talmu - If you read very carefully, the device is made from the worst parts and is  falsely being sold as repairable.

Comment: But this is a specific example, not the general term.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I had the same first instinct when I saw the question title, but a *cut and shut** is specifically not what the OP is looking for. In a "cut and shut" car the front end would be from a car that had had its rear damaged, and the rear end would be from a car that had had its front damaged. i.e. a "cut and shut" takes the "*good*" bits from damaged cars. (It is, however, still horrifically dangerous because the joining process makes it far inferior to an original car.) [cont...]

Comment: The OP wants a term for a car made from the damaged front end with the damaged back end, i.e. the *worst* of both bits.

Comment: @AndyT - good point.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK A lemon is frequently used for quite a different beast: something that is bought new, but dead on arrival; a dud. I don't recall hearing it used of something that's been slapped together from used pieces (though usage probably varies).

Comment: Plus one. The accepted answer, [a lemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_%28automobile%29) is what they're called in the US.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of hardware hack is known, in British English at least, as a [Kludge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+kludge&oq=define+kludge&gs_l=hp.3..0l3j0i30.1063.4781.0.4930.20.16.3.1.1.0.184.1530.6j8.14.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..5.15.1305.0.CO-FbBI7C5I).

The word is used for any system that is built from parts, possibly scrap or obsolete, taken from other machines.

The word can also be used for a temporary repair of a similar nature - a lash-up to get you home.

Comment: ... but wouldn't a kludge be quite obvious in most cases, and provide a clumsy, but working solution? On the risk of sounding too critical and not thankful, the device I have in mind looks perfect and has a lot of hidden flaws that won't show up before you turn it on or run deeper tests. It may actually be built to look not kludge-y at all with the aim of cheating and reaching a high resale price.

Comment: That would depend on the outward appearance.  if you put your dodgy components into a nice looking shiny box, it will fool a lot of the people a lot of the time.

Comment: @zebonaut I agree: A kludge usually works, albeit in strange and unusual ways. I think of a kludge as something MacGyver has put together. If may look awful and work sub-optimal but it gets the job done, at least for the moment.

Comment: Agreed, in the circles I frequent here in the US klu(d)ge refers to a clumsy, inelegant solution -- but generally one that gets the job done, and it's done with the intent that it gets the job done. The OP seems to be asking for the exact opposite: something that's put together cleanly and looks great, but with no intention of it ever actually working.

Answer (score 6):

"My friend was able to construct two usable laser printers, and one useless **Frankenstein** - which he sold anyway."

Comment: As something cobbled together from various bits and pieces a Frankenstein works for me. But I fail to see the implication that the end-result is a useless, non-functional, heap of parts. After all, the monster did live, didn't he ?

Comment: @Tonny He never functioned in normal society!

Comment: I *said* "useless" Frankenstein b/c that was the description in OP's question. I am the owner of a functioning Frankenstein computer and there are plenty of Frankenstein cars on the road - check out the recent articles on "the cars of Cuba". (Very cool)

Comment: @Oldbag The computer I'm typing this on is a Frankenstein with parts from at least 10 different sources. Case, PSU, motherboard is a HP Workstation, dual Xeon CPU's come from a Dell PowerEdge server, 8 strips of ECC-RAM from 3 different Proliant servers. Has 8 disks and only the SSD was bought, the rest come from 5 (6?) donors. I forget where the DVD burner and GFX-cardcame from. 2nd NIC, USB3 controller were bought and the keyboard is a Model M I rescued from a skip. But it all works perfectly. It's nodename on the network is Franky, for obvious reasons ;-)

Comment: But Dr. Frankenstein was a very capable scientist and certainly not _himself_ constructed from dead parts. **</pedantry>**.

Comment: @Useless -  Yeah, it's funny...  Did he ever bother to give the monster a name?  I confess, I tried to read it several times over the years, but Mary Shelley's writing gives me petit-mal seizures.  Perhaps, if the creation had a catchy name like "Liberace" or something, things would be different.

Comment: @Tonny - (Oh good, it's not just me...) : )

Comment: @CreationEdge - true, but that was as much a comment on society as on _Frankenstein's Monster_.

Comment: @Tonny It's telling that we still insist on calling him a monster and not a medical marvel

Comment: @Oldbag If I'm not misremembering, the monster’s name was _Adam_ (which doesn't quite work in this context, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

In American, it's called **[jury rigged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged)**. That's when you cobble something together in order to make it work. This only applies to the first two laser pointers, more so if you'd used parts from other manufacturers. The third one, as you say, is offered: *as is*.

The technical term is: *Broken @$$ piece of $#!^.*

Comment: While I agree that your technical term fits the requirements pretty well ;-), I guess it was something more subtle. We would have remembered "Broken @$$ piece of $#!^".

Comment: To me (born in California, living in Massachusetts) "jury rigged" is similar to the "kludge" answer given above -- it's a temporary (and frequently crappy) fix that's intended to get something working, rather than an attempt to put together a pile of known faulty parts only to make it *look* good.

Comment: "Jury rigged", is when there's corruption at the courthouse.  The actual term is "gerry-rigged" - (from a nickname for the Germans during WWII) a grudging appreciation of their ingenuity, in spite of a lack of parts, for various 'slap-dash' repairs made to weapons and vehicles. There is also a common American expression: "nigger-rigged" - which means the same thing, but is no longer popular - for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Oldbag: no, both are "actual terms." "Jury-rigged" actually seems to be the most common variant, and is also older than "jerry-rigged." The sense seems to be that of etymonline's "jury" in "jury-mast," with the meaning "temporary."  As far as I know, "jury-rigged" is never used  to refer to judicial corruption. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged

Comment: Jury rigging has nothing to do with the law. The term was widely used in a nautical context to refer to temporary repairs of sailing ships at sea. I think using this for deliberately fabricated rubbish is off the mark.

Comment: @Bobble - Agreed, see my comment on myol's answer, or read the link. It comes from the French word for *day*: 'jour'.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the word "similar to diva" was simply **defective**. "V" and "F" sounds may be hard for a non-native speaker to distinguish, since some languages don't contain both of them. If the OP's example, an honest seller might describe the third item as "known to be defective".

Comment: "Known to be defective" works. Defective itself doesn't necessarily imply malice.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the resulting product as a ***botch job***:

> An improvised and ultimately dishonest approach to repair so as only to provide a temporal verisimilitude of correct functionality.
>   <sub>[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=botch%20job)</sub>

Comment: Also related to [***hack job***](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/211750/87426).

Answer (score 1):

Something sold broken, but fixable, would be called a **fixer-upper**.

> fixer-upper: (noun) something (as a house or car) that needs fixing up

[merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixer-upper)

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what the OP was asking for.  They mean something that looks okay from the outside, but is in fact practically impossible to make work.

Answer (score 1):

When sold, your junk device could be called a *pup*, as in "[to be sold a pup](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+sold+a+pup)".

Answer (score 1):

**Jerry rigged**

[Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jerry-rig)

> To fix an object (usually mechanical) to a working condition in a haphazard way.

[Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jerry-rigged)

> Organized or constructed in a crude or improvised manner

Comment: "First known use: 1959" –MW, your link. See the [link in my answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132868/jury-rigged-or-jerry-rigged). SE consensus disagrees with WWII being the origin: *Jerry-masts or rigs derive their name from the the French jour, "day," indicating their temporary nature ....  "Jerry-rig" and "jerry-rigged" don't seem to have come into use until after World War II.*

Comment: Something that's been jerry-rigged is an a working state of some sort. This doesn't match with the OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

If a product is a **(ticking) time-bomb** it **will** fail at some indeterminate point in the future, with the implication that the flaw is hidden and will not be found until it "explodes".

Answer (score 0):

**Defunct** de·funct /dəˈfəNGkt/ adjective –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=defunct&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> no longer existing or functioning. *"a now defunct technology that only people over a certain age remember"*
> synonyms:  disused, unused, inoperative, nonfunctioning, unusable, obsolete
>
> Origin: mid 16th century (in the sense ‘deceased’): from Latin defunctus ‘dead,’ past participle of defungi ‘carry out, finish,’ from de- (expressing reversal) + fungi ‘perform.’

Cannibalized to reconstruct two other units, all components are present, however the entire assembly is defunct. No refunds.

Answer (score -1):

Ford.  Which is the common abbreviation for Fix Or Repair Daily.

Comment: Not to be confused with a *seadoo redoo*.

Answer (score -1):

Well, with any eccentric device, such as the outlandish breakfast making machine made by Potts in Chitty Chitty Bang Bang, you can say it's 'Heath Robinson'.

This refers to the eponymous English artist who created drawings of mad machines.

I have commonly heard such machines described thus, in the UK.

Example: It's very 'Heath Robinson', that crazy machine!

The Wikipedia link notes the use of his name to mean 'any unnecessarily complex and implausible contrivance', used in both the UK and USA.

Very worth looking at his wonderfully clever and funny drawings, as well.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson

And as for Potts, how I wish I had a machine like his:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RBJGpNTP_lY

Comment: "Heath Robinson" means overly complicated. It does *not* mean "full of broken parts".

Comment: Oh really? @AndyT: From Wikipedia: "In the UK, the term "Heath Robinson" entered the popular language during the 1914–1918 First World War as a description of any unnecessarily complex and implausible contrivance, ..."Heath Robinson contraption" is perhaps more often used in relation to temporary fixes using ingenuity and whatever is to hand, often string and tape, or unlikely cannibalisations. Its continuing popularity was undoubtedly linked to Britain's shortages and the need to "make do and mend" during the Second World War."

Comment: So.... your quote completely backs up my previous comment? I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: How are 'unlikely cannibalisations' and 'temporary fixes using ingenuity and whatever is to hand' not referring to reusing parts of broken machines? @AndyT

Comment: @Jelila: The OP refers to an item that **doesn't work** made from **broken parts**, quite dissimilar to **working items** temporarily fixed using **working parts** from inoperable machines.

Comment: Oh well then @PaulDirac it could be a 'White Elephant': https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant_sale

Comment: @Jelila: " an extravagant but burdensome gift that cannot be easily disposed of, based on the legend of the King of Siam gifting rare albino elephants to courtiers who had displeased him, that they might be ruined by the animals' upkeep costs". It's not really the same as the thing the OP was referring to is it?

Comment: Well I'm not just going on 'what is written in Wikipedia' @PaulDirac. I'm going on my own personal knowledge of English. And a 'white elephant' and a 'white elephant sale' is somewhere where people sell off - obsolete items that kind of don't fit in anywhere - rather like broken old pieces of printer! The origin of the phrase may be from the King of Siam but it has a broader meaning than speciifically referring to unwanted animals.

Comment: @Jelila: At no stage did I say the term “white elephant” referred only to animals, its meaning is quite clear from the reference I quoted (that you supplied). “white elephant sale” and the characterisation you provided  is even further away from the term the OP was looking for then either of your previous two attempts. Perhaps you should use your **own personal knowledge of English** and find a term that might be useful to the OP rather than raising(and persisting) with red herrings.

Comment: @Jelila: I can understand why you would not be **just going on what is written in Wikipedia**, you have referenced it twice in these comments alone, each time it was contrary to the point you were trying to make. If something was as equally unfaithful to me I would probably disown it too.

Comment: Well, I choose to differ. If I were writing a piece on re-used junk I would most likely use Heath Robinson, and that's what I'd use if I was speaking as well. otherwise, I would say white elephant or maybe bric-a-brac. I'm not on trial here, I am merely offering my suggestions and my point of view.

Answer (score -2):

The Japanese have [Chindōgu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chind%C5%8Dgu) which are inventions that are purposely created to solve a problem (that may not have existed in the first place) but are really just useless.

> ***Wikipedia:***  Chindōgu is the Japanese art of inventing ingenious everyday gadgets that, on the face of it, seem like an ideal solution to a particular problem. However, chindōgu has a distinctive feature: anyone actually attempting to use one of these inventions would find that it causes so many new problems, or such significant social embarrassment, that effectively it has no utility whatsoever. Thus, chindōgu are sometimes described as "unuseless" – that is, they cannot be regarded as "useless" in an absolute sense, since they do actually solve a problem; however, in practical terms, they cannot positively be called "useful".

This answer is a bit tangential from the OP's question but does describe a set of inventions that are deliberately broken or "unuseless".

Comment: Impatient users term it * junk*. When officially sold at half rate/discounted price the same is  " seconds", particularly clothes.